# How to attach last records in relation with eloquent in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have a group table, messages table, and users table.
The messages table belongs to one user and morphTo a group.
the groups table belongs to one user and morphMany messages.
I want to get all groups related to one user with the last messages "only the last message".

```
`users Model`
public function messages(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Message');
}
public function groups(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Group', 'group_user');
}


`Groups Model`
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function messages(){
    return $this->morphMany('App\Message', 'messagable');
}



`messages model`
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function messagable(){
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

I want the result to be like that:

```
{
"id": 23,
"user_id": 2,
"name": "Group1",
"description": "5656",
"img": "images/1524958644.png",
"created_at": "2018-04-28 23:37:24",
"updated_at": "2018-04-28 23:37:24",
"last_messages":{
    "id": 292,
    "user_id": 1,
    "messagable_type": "App\\Group",
    "messagable_id": 23,
    "message": "hi",
    "created_at": "2018-04-29 07:48:55",
    "updated_at": "2018-04-29 07:48:55"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) for this.

eg. In your Groups model

```
protected $appends = ['last_message'];


public function getLastMessageAttribute()
{
    return $this->messages->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
}
```

You could also use `orderBy` with `created_at` instead of `id`

You can then retrieve it by using this as an example:

```
Group::where('user_id',2)->first()->last_message;
```

Comment: I used  "return $this->messages->sortKeysDesc()->first();" in the accessor and I got what I wanted but with also extra info: (I got the lst message and all the messages as well). Is there a way that can hide all the messages?

Comment: I added "protected $hidden = ['messages'];" in my model and now everything is fine.

Comment: It seems I gave you the correct answer to find what you were looking for, you just didn't provide enough information. Glad you worked it out.